# Brand new HP elitebook mutes itself when I press "dd" on keyboard

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, keyboard

**Issue:**

This might sound like a "pebkac" issue, but I truly thing my laptop is defective.  It is a brand new work HP elitebook with a clean install of Windows 10, and when I press the "d" key in succession two times, the speaker/headphones mute.

I can also press "d" then any other keys, then the second "d" press will mute it.  Ex. "d alsdjflakjsdlfa d".  If I press keys somewhat together with it, such as "sdsdsdsdsd" where I rock my fingers on them, it does not have the issue.

It does it directly on the laptop with no devices attached and with 2 different brand-new keyboards.

**Questions:**

1. Is there an app/script I can run in the short term that will un-mute my audio over and over while it's running?
2. Is there anything I could do to fix this, or is it likely a defect? I'm in the process of talking to HP, but in the interim this drives me insane

Comment: Does this behavior happen when you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Don't waste your time. If it is brand new, and you believe it is defective, call HP Support.

Comment: @Ramhound - Unable to boot into safemode because of bitlocker. Working with IT admin on that.

Comment: @CharlieRB - I think you're right. Right now I'm just trying to alleviate the symptom because I need the music/noise to work. I have a powershell script that unmutes, but task scheduler only lets you run in increments of 1 minute and I don't see any event in the event viewer for mute events.

Comment: @AlexK - Your questions cannot be answered until you confirm if the behavior happens in Safe Mode or not.

Comment: @Ramhound - In windows 10, you can't enable audio in safemode without adding a bunch of registry keys...which I did, and it does not have the issue. I finally tracked down what program it was. "hp - Bang & Olufsen Audio"?? Some HP Audio thing.

Comment: @AlexK - Safe Mode, minimal configuration, not a great deal of difference between the two.  I use the term Safe Mode since everyone knows that term, using minimal configuration, has in the past caused problems with people understanding what I was suggesting they do.

Comment: @Ramhound So `Safe Boot - Minimal` has more options than `Safe Boot - Network`? I just selected network because I didn't have any audio files handy on this computer and accessing the internet seemed more important to me. Does `Minimal` include network?  But thank you for the help either way. Once in safe mode, not having the issue made me start killing random applications until it stopped happening.

Comment: @AlexK - A minimal configure is not Safe Mode, its what ever configuration gets you booting, but nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was.  Some HP program called "Bang & Olufsen Audio" or listed under Startup as "SmartAudio CPL (32bit)".

File location is: 
`C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\SA3\HP-NB-AIO\sacpl.exe`

When I killed this process, it solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Zbook 15u G3 Studio Workstation had the same problem.  "D" key mutes audio.  Opened Task Manager, and Disabled the Conexant / Bang & Olufsen SmartAudio CPL.  Mute button functions normally, "D" key no longer mutes, but LED status of mute function stuck in the Muted indication.

Comment: It's a bizarre issue. It went away for a while with a driver update, but another driver update reintroduced another muting issue, but this time it was some other key(s), so I had to disable again. I think it also controls the pop-ups that say "You unplugged a device", which would fire randomly when my headphones never became unplugged

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me on my HP 15" Zbook in the last week or two.  Just this week, I figured out it was the 'd' key that was muting my audio out.  Like AlexK mentioned, I rolled back the audio driver update from 2 weeks ago and now it is thankfully gone.

Answer (score 0):

On my HP ProBook 430 G4, with Windows 10, I had the same issue (D key would mute the audio.) None of the above fixes worked, I suspect some of the executable names have changed with this latest driver version. But I found that finding and renaming mictray64.exe, and then rebooting, fixed the issue. The only side effect I can see is that the microphone muting function (Fn-F10) isn't working anymore. But I can live with that. Also, the annoying B&O audio control panel is gone, which makes me very happy! It was buggy, there was no way to make it disappear at times.